# How do I Take 2D array with variable columns as input from user in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, dynamic-arrays

I want to take a 2D array with each element as an input from user.
However, I want the user to specify in each array(i.e the column part or the each individual array) how many elements are there i.e taking variable columns.

I entered the following code:

```
System.out.print("enter no. of rows: ");
        int rows = sc.nextInt();

        int[][] arr = new int[rows][];

        for (int r=0; r<arr.length; r++) {
            System.out.print("Enter no. of elements in array "+r +": ");
            int col = sc.nextInt();

            for (int c=0; c<col;c++){

                System.out.print("Enter element "+c +": ");
                arr[r][c] = sc.nextInt();
            }
        }

        for (int[] x :
                arr) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));
        }
```

It should take input of a 2D array with variable columns as defined by user and print it.
But,
It shows the following error:
[Error in code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6i0E.png)

---

However when I define the number of columns it works fine.
like this:

```
System.out.print("enter no. of rows: ");
    int rows = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter no. of elements in each array : ");
    int col = sc.nextInt();
    int[][] arr = new int[rows][col];

    for (int r=0; r<arr.length; r++) {


        for (int c=0; c<col;c++){

            System.out.print("Enter element "+c +": ");
            arr[r][c] = sc.nextInt();
        }
    }

    for (int[] x :
            arr) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));
    }
}
```

---

Comment: Do not use the `dsa` tag.  The `dsa` tag is for `Digital Signature Algorithm`.

Comment: Assumes `rows=3`. When you do `new int[rows][];`, you created an array like `[null, null, null]`. When you do `new int[rows][2]`, you get `[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]`. You need to initialize those arrays yourself if you're using variable dimensions. Basically, you created an array of `int[]` (an object, which defaults to `null`) vs `int[col]` (an array of length `col`, with default values of 0).

Answer (score 0):

The below code takes input from user for the Columns and Rows and Insert values according asking from user to input the value and then Prints them for users reference.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Get the dimensions of the array from the user
        System.out.print("Enter the number of rows: ");
        int rows = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the number of columns: ");
        int columns = scanner.nextInt();

        // Create a 2D array based on user input
        int[][] array = new int[rows][columns];

        // Take input for each element of the array
        System.out.println("Enter the elements of the array:");

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                System.out.print("Enter element at position [" + i + "][" + j + "]: ");
                array[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();
            }
        }

        // Print the elements of the array
        System.out.println("The array is:");

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();  // Move to the next line after each row
        }

        // Close the scanner to avoid resource leak
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

> Refer the working code [here](https://onlinegdb.com/afbLtuZfU)

Comment: but this defines static no of columns i.e for every array there will be fixed no of elements I want the user to input how many elements does the each array contain.

Comment: That is being catered by above program it asked for array size from user

Answer (score 0):

It works using the following code:

```
System.out.print("enter no. of rows: ");
    int rows = sc.nextInt();

    int col = 10;
    int[][] arr = new int[rows][col];

    for (int r=0; r<arr.length; r++) {

        System.out.printf("Enter no. of elements in array %d (should be less than 10): ",r+1);
        col = sc.nextInt();

        for (int c=0; c<col;c++){

            System.out.printf("Enter element [%d][%d]: ",r+1,c+1);
            arr[r][c] = sc.nextInt();
        }
    }
```

The col  numbers however must be less than the ones defined statically.